# Error Maven install in Jenkins Pipeline: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jenkins, devops

This is my first Devops project. I created a pipeline on jenkins that pulls from a spring boot project on github then executes Maven commands. Then Sonar Nexus and Docker. And i have this compatibility error at the maven install stage that i can't fix:

```
+ mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for tn.esprit.rh:achat:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.exclusions.exclusion.artifactId' for org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar with value '*' does not match a valid id pattern. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.5.3, /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.5.3/spring-boot-dependencies-2.5.3.pom, line 1691, column 25
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building achat 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.059s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Nov 12 19:01:24 UTC 2022
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/29M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) on project achat: The plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0 requires Maven version 3.1.0 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginIncompatibleException
```

This is the content of pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>tn.esprit.rh</groupId>
    <artifactId>achat</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>achat</name>
    <description>Projet pour le module DevOps</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.3.0</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

This is Java and Maven configuration on the Vagrant CentOS7 VM from where i'm launching Jenkins:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 11.0.17, vendor: Red Hat, Inc., runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.17.0.8-2.el7_9.x86_64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-1160.76.1.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

This is maven configuration in Jenkins Global Tool Configuration: [![Global tool config maven]:
Name: M2_HOME
MAVEN_HOME: /opt/maven

I tried all the fixes i could think of or find on internet but it's a pretty specifix problem that's why i'm posting it here.

Comment: Does your Jenkins have any Maven plug in installed?

Comment: First the jenkins setup does not see the maven version because of the given error: `maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0 requires Maven version 3.1.0`... If you configured the global tools configuration the usage of `M2_HOME` does not work because those are environment variables which are related to the environment of your starting process (Jenkins!)... You should simply configure the absolute path to your Maven installation in your Jenkins Setup...

Comment: Also defining a maven-plugin as a dependency in your project is simply wrong. Remove the dependency to `maven-compiler-plugin`...

Comment: @khmarbaise even after configuring the absolute path in the jenkins setup, jenkins still doesn't see Maven. Is there something specific i need to restart for the changes to be seen ?